# Batch convert the bit depth of several audio files from 32 to 16

Tags: bit-depth

Is there a reasonable way to batch convert the bit depth of several audio files from 32 to 16?

With Adobe Audition, I can open a file, then "Save As..." and change it to 16 bit. But I have hundreds of files now.

Comment: I use twisted wave for this kind of work.

Comment: It's fairly simple, depending on the software. However, do read up on 'Dithering'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Adobe Audition there's a built-in batch processor: Edit > Batch Process

Answer (score 3):

Using [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) (Windows, Linux, Mac):

```
cd /where/your/wav/files/are/
mkdir converted
for i in *.wav; do sox -S "$i" -b 32 converted/"$i"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

The batch processing feature of GoldWave will do the trick.
[image]

Comment: It doesn't have a dither option, I think that would be handy when converting bit depth. Does Goldwave support dithering?

Answer (score 1):

I love compressor for this! You can even create Drag and drop areas to Speed up the process of file conversion!